# Setting up equations in a mixing problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In an exercise sheet for solving 2x2 systems of ODE's, the following question came up:

"Consider two tanks, A and B, each holding 200 litres of water. A pipe pumps
water from tank A to tank B at a rate of 5 l/min. At the same time another
pipe pumps liquid from tank B to tank A at the same rate. At time t = 0, $x_0$
kg of a chemical X is dissolved into tank A, and tank B has $y_0$ kg of the same
chemical X dissolved into it.

Write down the system of differential equations satisfied by $x(t)$ and $y(t)$,
the quantity of the chemical X in tanks A and B respectively."

However I am really lost as to how to set up these systems of equations.

Comment: Think of what happens one minute after the chemicals have been added: in tank A there are 200 liters of the mixture, 195 of them have concentration $\frac{x_0}{200}$, while the other 5 have concentration $\frac{y_0}{200}$. I guess you have to assume that chemicals dissolve instantly and that as the liquid flows from one tank to the other the concentration ajdusts also instantaneously.

Comment: You should not delete questions after you have received an answer (especially a detailed and painstaking one). It is very poor etiquette. I had to flag for moderator intervention to have the deletion reversed.

Answer (score 0):

In a small time interval, tank A is losing chemical in proportion to what is currently within it, but also gaining chemical in proportion to what is currently in the other tank (B).

The situation is exactly mirrored for tank B.

At all times, the volumes of liquid in each tank remains constant at $200$ litres. The proportion of the liquid of one tank transferred to the other (and vice-versa) in a minute is always $\frac 5{200} = \frac 1{40}$.

Denote the small time interval $\Delta t$. The change in $x$ in tank A is given by:

$\Delta x = (-\frac 1{40}x +  \frac 1{40}y) \Delta t$

And the change in $y$ in tank B is given by:

$\Delta y = (+\frac 1{40}x -  \frac 1{40}y) \Delta t$

Dividing throughout by $\Delta t$ and taking the limit $\Delta t \to 0$ allows us to arrive at:

$\displaystyle 40\frac {dx} {dt} = y-x$

and

$\displaystyle 40\frac {dy} {dt} = x - y$

The next steps in the problem will probably involve you solving this system (to do that, try subtracting the second from the first and introduce the variable $z = x-y$).